# Trait A can only be extended by class that extends Trait B

Tags: scala, traits

Say I have two traits (A and B) and a class C which mixes them in and implements their methods:

```
trait A {
    def foo
}

trait B {
    def bar
}    

class C extends A with B {
    def foo = "Foo"
    def bar = "Bar"
}
```

Is there any way in Scala to specify that the class that extends trait B must extend trait A and then use the implemented method of trait A's defined method in trait B?

So that B could call `this.foo()` and access the value that has been returned by C's implementation?

Answer (score 6):

Just specify what you want `this` to be:

```
trait B { this: A =>
  def bar = this.foo
}
```

This is so called *self type* and `this` here is an alias rather than keyword (so self: A, that: A and so on are perfectly legal).

Comment: A note aside: It often raises some confusion that the self type is *not* part of the public API of `B`. I.e. if you have an instance of `B`, you won't be able to call `foo` on it.

Comment: Is the inaccessibility of `foo` from outside the only difference with `trait B extends A` ?